# Expose docker-compose windows containers to windows host network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'im fairly new to docker and docker compose.
I have a simple scenario, based on three applications (app1, app2, app3) that I want to connect to my host's network. The purpose is having an internet connection also inside the container.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    app1container:
        image: app1img
        build: ./app1
        networks:
            network_comp:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.1.1
        extra_hosts: 
            anotherpc: 192.168.1.44
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 8080:8080
    app2container:
        depends_on: 
            - "app1container"
        image: app2img
        build: ./app2
        networks:
            network_comp:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.1.2
        ports:
            - 3100:3100
    app3container:
        depends_on: 
            - "app1container"
        image: app3img
        build: ./app3
        networks:
            network_comp:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.1.3
        ports:
            - 9080:9080

networks:
    network_comp:
        driver: ""
        ipam:
            driver: ""
            config:
                - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
                  gateway: 192.168.1.254
```

I already read the docker-compose documentation, which says that there is no a bridge driver for Windows OS. Is there anyway a solution to this issue?

Comment: You don't normally give individual processes on a physical system their own IP addresses, running in containers or otherwise.  You should be able to use the host system's IP address and the first published `ports:` number to access the containers.  Specifying Docker-internal IP addresses that conflict with the external network could cause problems, and you might delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the whole file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't usually need to do any special setup for this to work.  When your Compose service has `ports:`, that makes a port available on the *host's* IP address.  The essential rules for this are:

1. The service inside the container must listen on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address (not 127.0.0.1 "this container only"), on some (usually fixed) port.
2. The container must be started with Compose `ports:` (or `docker run -p`).  You choose the first port number, the second port number must match the port inside the container.
3. The service can be reached via the host's IP address on the first port number (or, if you're using the older Docker Toolbox setup, on the `docker-machine ip` address).

```
  http://host.example.com:12345  (from other hosts)
             |
             v
     ports: ['12345:8080']       (in the `docker-compose.yml`)
             |
             v
./my_server -bind 0.0.0.0:8080   (the main container command)
```

You can remove all of the manual `networks:` configuration in this file.  In particular, it's problematic if you try to specify the Docker network to have the same IP address range as the host network, since these are two separate networks.  Compose automatically provides a network named `default` that should work for most practical applications.